# How to verify the "random sampling" Gauss-Markov Assumption with Stata (or anything else)?

Tags: regression, least-squares, assumptions

According to the book I am using,  *Introductory Econometrics* by J.M. Wooldridge, there are 5 Gauss-Markov assumptions necessary to obtain BLUE.

However, by looking in other literature, there is one of Wooldridge's assumption I do not recognize, i.e. the so-called "Random Sampling" assumption according to which "We have a random sample of n observations $(x_{i1}, x_{i2}, \dots, x_{ik}, y_i): i= 1, \dots, n)$ following the population model".

I am trying to figure out how to test this assumption on my data, knowing that my supervisor is looking for a proof more solid than simply saying my data was obtained randomly.

Could you please help on this? I am using Stata for any statistical tests.

P.S. I am aware of the 6th assumption (normality of errors) in order to obtain valid statistical inference.

Comment: Are you asking how to check whether your sample has been obtained by random sampling from your population? As in to check whether there is some dependence in your observations?

Comment: The sample won't (can't) tell you how it was produced in the same way that you can't tell whether 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 are just numbers I made up or the results of a series of coin tosses (tails 1, heads 0).

Comment: @user2974951  I basically have to verify each of the Gauss-Markov assumptions (Linearity, Random Sampling, No Perfect Collinearity, Zero Conditional Mean and Homoskedasticity) plus the Normality assumption. 

For each assumption I used a test (Breusch-Pagan, Shapiro-Wilk etc.) and scatterplots to verify linearity for example. I am wondering how to justify the Random sampling one...

Comment: @NickCox Very true, according to your argument, my justification would simply be based on good faith ?

Comment: No such implication on my part. The point is that the sampling credentials of data are to be sought in how they were sampled (measured, produced), not in what they are or seem like. If one does not know, then that underlines the ignorance of the researcher; it doesn't establish the innocence of the data.

Comment: You could estimate autocorrelation to check whether there is significant correlation / dependence between your observations, and that's as far as you can go.

Comment: The detail depends on whether on your definition random sampling implies independence.

Comment: @user2974951 Thank you, I will verify it as well, by looking at other papers verifying the same assumptions, it seems that the assumption "no serial correlation" is often verified within the context of the Gauss-Markov Theorem

Comment: @NickCox The data was used through a survey that I did myself. I sent it to as many entities as possible. I did not select these entities, I just tried to reach as many of them as I could.

Comment: So that's important information not in the question. There are at least three matters to address. 1. What is your population? 2. In what sense would your sampling design ideally produce a random sample? 3. Consideration of the implications of selective response (non-response). The same questions and difficulties arise for a large fraction of social science studies.

Comment: Although one cannot establish from the data alone that they realize a "random sample" (in the usual senses that imply, at a minimum, exchangeability of the observations) of any population or process, it is nevertheless possible to measure data characteristics that suggest the sample is *non-random.* This is the idea behind testing the goodness of pseudorandom number generators, for instance. These are usually large batteries of tests for various patterns arising from common failures of randomization. This idea could serve as a good starting point for your data.